# Iterating over object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the most efficient / elegant way to iterate object values in JavaScript?

As an example, assume the following object: `let myObj = {p1: "v1", p2: "v2"}`

Comment: Try searching for "stackoverflow iterate object properties".

Comment: @torazaburo I did, and the results are either outdated, incomplete or discuss frameworks. Note that I have also posted answer to my own question in an attempt to summarize the possible solutions in modern ES.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties also has useful answers, although some of them are quite deeply buried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ECMAScript 2017:**

If your target platform supports [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values(myObj).forEach(value => /* do something */)
```

If you need the property names as well, you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in combination with [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, value]) => /* do something */)
```

**ECMAScript 5:**

If you need to be backwards compatible and don't want to use a polyfill:

```
Object.keys(myObj).map(prop => myObj[prop]).forEach(value => /* do something */)
```

**Older versions:**

Note that the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterates over prototype's properties as well, so you need to filter them out using [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```
for (var key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = myObj[key];
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: For completeness, also show `for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myObj))`.